# Rails - RouteTranslator Gem - Generates too many languages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Another day with Rails...
I have tried this [RouteTranlsator Gem](https://github.com/enriclluelles/route_translator). I have done the steps from 1st to 4th but when I run `rake routes` command. I see that the rake generated routes for more 6 languages! Like fr, de, cs, nl,... But I localized only two languages: en (english) and hu (hungarian). I did not create any translation .yml files for the other languages!

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".
  localized do
    resources :partners
    resources :school_reviews, except: [:edit]
    resources :schools
    resources :events

    # Authentication
    devise_for :users, :controllers => { 
        omniauth_callbacks: "users/omniauth_callbacks", registrations: 'registrations'
    }
    devise_scope :user do
      get 'sign_up_with_school' => 'registrations#new_with_school', as: 'sign_up_with_school'
      post 'sign_up_with_school' => 'registrations#create_with_school', as: 'create_with_school'
    end
  end
end
```

And I defined only hu (hungarian) translations:
hu:
  routes:
    new: uj
    create: letrehozas
    edit: szerkesztes
    destroy: torles
    partners: partnerek
    school_reviews: iskolai_velemenyek
    schools:  iskolak
    events: esemnyek

Maybe some other gems cause this more 6 languages? **How can I disable the fr, de, cs and other languages?**

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have solved it.
This line has to be added in environments.

`config.i18n.available_locales = [:en, :hu]`